# RSS feeds don't have an icon

Tags: bug, feed

I'm using [RSS Feed Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp) to keep track of certain blogs and a few stackexchange-related feeds.

Related to stackexchange I'm following both

> https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=roslyn&sort=newest

and

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/88656/answers&body=true

As you can see from this screenshot, the first one doesn't give me an icon while the others do. Can we also have an icon for the "normal" feeds, or is this a problem on my end (re-adding the feed doesn't make a difference and no other site has this problem)?

[image]

The same happens for Code Review as well. I should note that the first few minutes an icon is shown but simply disappears after that.